# Short shareable URL for aliexpress item?

Tags: url-shortening, aliexpress

Are builtin short URL's to share an item available in [aliexpress](https://aliexpress.com)?

If so, what's the format?

(Something like eBay has `/itm/xxxxxxx`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest form of an AliExpress item's URL is:

`aliexpress.com/item/XXXXXXXXXXX.html`

Notes:

- This is without making use of any third-party services which may inject affiliate codes.
- Prior to a change in 2020, the format used to be `aliexpress.com/item/-/XXXXXXXXXXX.html`, where the dash was used in place of the item's name in the URL. This part of the url is no longer necessary and at the time of writing, will be redirected to `aliexpress.com/item/XXXXXXXXXXX.html`, but don't rely on this always being the case.

Comment: I have to give props to the folks over at `alixpress.ml` who have their own URL shortener that uses the advertiser API to silently inject their affiliate link and then directs the user to the URL format given in the answer. For those curious, their shortened format is `http://alixpress.ml/?k=XXXXXXXXXXX`.

Comment: How you discovered that a dash should be there? :O

Comment: Reverse engineering. I just traced the series of HTTP redirects performed by the URL shortener in the above comment (using the Network tab of the developer console).

Comment: Add the item to the wish list, and from there you'll see the short url, exactly this form (+ a query parameter, but that's easy to delete).

Comment: @arieljannai the dash is redundant. the links work with a double slash.

Comment: @naXa as of the 2020 site redesign, that part of the url isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's the shortest possible option. I hope the following steps will be helpful.

1. Go to a product page. In the beginning, you'll see something like 
   https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-Badges-for-Clothing/32822967746.html?spm=2114.search0604.3.155.7ca25ef0zLx1Pc&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0 in the address bar.
2. Remove the part after `?`
3. Remove `www.`
4. If you browse a local version of AliExpress remove subdomain as well (e.g. remove `ru.`)
5. Replace the part between `item/` and the next `/` with anything you want (except `/` of course) or even leave it blank
6. Change protocol from `https://` to `http://`. Note: if you remove the protocol at all some services fail to recognise the resulting text as a link.

In the end, you should get a short link http://aliexpress.com/item//32822967746.html

Share your ideas for further improvement =)

Comment: Why need to use http instead of https? Looks like it can work with https.

Comment: @Ashark I agree, it works with HTTPS. But HTTP is 1 character shorter. Look at the question.

Comment: Ah, only that thing in mind. Ok, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://ali.onl/ URL shortener.

example link: http://ali.onl/18Gp
traffic statistics: http://ali.onl/18Gp+